# vba - Macro producing incorrect results when run, but when stepping into results are correct

Tags: vba, excel, macros, vlookup

I have a macro that inserts a `VLOOKUP` into a column. The macro has to take a number stored as text and convert it to a number, before looking up that number in another sheet.

The macro always produces the same results, such as reaching row 43 before starting to produce erroneous results however when using `F8` to step through the code, these incorrect results are not produced.

The erroneous results are that the value placed into col 13 is not equal to the number stored as text. Mostly it seems as though values from rows above and below, sometimes 2 rows below are being inserted to col 13. Almost seems to me as if 2 different threads are running at 2 different speeds or something?

If anyone could have a look at the loop causing the errors I would be grateful, thanks.

```
For counter = 2 To NumRowsList
  checker = CInt(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(counter, 3)    
  Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(counter, 13).Value = checker

  'Call WaitFor(0.5)
  If checker < 4000 Then
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(counter, 14) = "=VLOOKUP(M" & counter & ",Sheet4!E2:F126,2,FALSE)"
  Else
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(counter, 14) = "=VLOOKUP(M" & counter & ",Sheet5!B2:C200,2,FALSE)"
  End If        
Next counter
```

I have tried a few similar variations of this code, such as using the value stored in col 13 directly rather than using the cell reference in the `VLOOKUP`, always producing the same results.

I even used the waitfor function to try and create a delay hoping it may synchronise the operations, but it did not help and using a delay of more than 0.5 would cause the run time of the macro to be too big.

UPDATE:
I did not find a perfect solution, only a long hand work around. I simply combined the Vlookups onto a single sheet, and converted the numbers stored as text to numbers outside of the vba routine. This took the error away from the number calculation (just col C * 1), and then the vlookups were looking up the correct values. Thank you for the help, regardless.

Comment: VBA doesn't support multiple threads.  Am I right in thinking this is the problem line: `Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(counter, 13).Value = checker`?  It sources its data from Sheet2 column 3.  Does that column contain a formula or a value?

Comment: Yeah, tbh I was just guessing. No col 3 has the number stored as text. it produces the same result if it has .value or not.

Comment: Are any of the values in col C > 32,767 ?

Comment: no they are between 1000 -  5000. I am completely stumped by the issue, since it runs correctly when stepped into one line at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can avoid looping, `checker` and all those `If-Then-Else`, like follows

**edited** to account for `VlookUp` range depending on `VlookUp` value

```
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    .Range("N2", .Cells(NumRowsList, 14)).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(Value(RC3),IF(Value(RC3)<4000,Sheet4!R2C5:R126C6,Sheet4!R2C2:R200C3),2,FALSE)"
End With
```

Comment: The range alteration isn't dependent on the row number but the value in the row, so this approach wouldn't work.

Comment: what do you mean? Have you tested it?

Comment: with `FormulaR1C1` notation, `RC3` means "current row - column 3", hence written formulas will always reference the row index of the cell they are in

Comment: @Flephal, my last two comments were for you

Comment: Cheers for the input guys, I will see if I can implement this solution. So far I figured out a work around which was a little long but accomplished what I wanted.

Comment: @Mojojojo, ok. but did you try this (short indeed) solution?

Comment: @user3598756 I had already used the long work around before I had seen your comment, but just had an opportunity and your idea also would've been sufficient. I have validated your response above to show this. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So, out of curiosity, what are you going to use in your code?

Comment: It was just a 1 off macro I was writing that was for 20 or so projects, categorising rows based on a workitem column in order to attribute separate costs to those categories. All submitted now.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me with my test data, but you'll need to see if it works for you... (also are you turning off calculation or events? I don't know if this might have an issue?)

I find it preferable to set a reference to the sheet you want to use rather than access it directly, and this may help?

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim VLURange As String, checker As Long

For counter = 2 To 200 ' NumRowsList
    checker = CLng(ws.Cells(counter, 3).Value)
    ws.Cells(counter, 13) = checker
    VLURange = IIf(checker < 4000, "Sheet4!E2:F126", "Sheet5!B2:C200")
    ws.Cells(counter, 14) = "=VLOOKUP(M" & counter & ", " & VLURange & ", 2, FALSE)"
Next counter
```